# How to read a dataframe content as normal content in pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am reading a binary file, whose content looks like:

| path | modificationTime | length | content |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| file:/C:/Users/G0... | 2023-05-04 18:39:... | 2130 | [F0 F0 F2 F0 F2 F... |

I want *content* column to be converted to normal text, instead of being hexadecimal `{[F0 F0 F2 F0 F2 F}`. Using apache spark.